# Mozilla firefox using "@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)"

Tags: html, css

good afternoon, I made a target to a html button with normal default style, and I noticed it does not style properly on mozilla, so I used the default style for mozilla and used **"@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)"** to target chrome, now my problem is that Mozilla is using **"@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)"** for its style. I mean instead of using the mozilla css which is the default style, it goes on to use webkit chrome styling thereby, it does not respond to the default style. CODE

```
<div class="fruits_holder_text_1">
<span>The <br/> Splash <br/> Strawberries</span>
<a class="fruits_holder_text_1_a" href="fruits/strawberries" title="Shop Now"><span>Shop Now</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;<img data-src="file_image/right2.png"></a>
</div>

  .fruits_holder_text_1 > .fruits_holder_text_1_a { /*mozilla*/
position:absolute;
margin-left:-37px;
margin-top:85px;
}


@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
.fruits_holder_text_1 > .fruits_holder_text_1_a {
position:absolute;
margin-left:-17px;
margin-top:10px;
}
}
```

//WHEN I CHECKED MY INSPECT ELEMENT ON FIREFOX, HERE IS WHAT I FOUND, MOZILLA IS USING CHROME WEBKIT, IMAGE BELOW.
[image: The button here]

[image: Image showing my inspect element, mozilla using the webkit style target]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Firefox 49 Mozilla introduced the ability to understand and work with "-webkit" properties.[1](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/09/firefox-49-fixes-sites-designed-with-webkit-in-mind-and-more/)
I think that's still working.